# tableau flag an account if it has two owners

Tags: tableau-desktop

The data source contains two column: account and owner. I want to create a calculated column to identify if an account has two different owners.

Data Source:

| account | owner |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | c |

Now I want a calculated column to flag "Yes" for an account if it has owner a & c. So the result would be:

| account | owner | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | no |
| 1 | b | no |
| 2 | a | no |
| 3 | a | yes |
| 3 | c | yes |
| 4 | c | no |

Any idea how this calculated column's formula looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself. Basically first create a column with 1 if it the owner is a, 2 if the owner is c, and 0 if owner is not a or c. Then create the final column to calculate the total of each account, so if the total is 3 then assign yes, otherwise assign no.

Make sure to use {fixed account: sum(calculated_column1)}

Comment: A simpler and more general approach is to learn to use boolean aggregate calculations, and probably also sets. learn how Min() and Max() apply to boolean fields since Tableau treats True > False. So you could have, for example, {fixed account: max(owner="a") and max(owner="b"). That will return true for those accounts that have a record showing a as the owner and also a record showing b as the owner - even if the account also has other owners. You could extend/revise for other conditions